# Running SVN update within ColdFusion app

Tags: svn, coldfusion

I am trying to do trigger an svn update within my ColdFusion application.  I have the following codes,

```
<cfset variables.svnexe = "c:\Progra~1\Collabnet\Subver~1\svn.exe">
<cfset variables.svnarg = " up ">
<cfset variables.svnarg = variables.svnarg & "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mybranch\ ">
<cfset variables.svnarg = variables.svnarg & "--username myusername --password myPassword">

<cfexecute variable="temp" name="#variables.svnexe#" arguments="#variables.svnarg#"  timeout="1000">    
</cfexecute>
```

The problem I have is that when I run the equivalent command in command line, (i.e.

```
c:\Progra~1\Collabnet\Subver~1\svn.exe up c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mybranch\ --username myusername --password myPassword
```

), it works completely good.  By "it works", I mean I can see the update in my folder after running the command in command line.  However, when I run the ColdFusion application, it is not giving me any errors but it is not doing what it is supposed to do either.

I have tried putting the svn command in a batch file and run it in ColdFusion.  The same thing happens, it works when I run in command line but not in the ColdFusion app.

My question is, what could be the reason?  And how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Comment: Does the process the coldfusion service is running under have permission to write to the working copy you're trying to update?

Comment: I would say that it should.  I am trying on my local box right now and the folder that I am trying to update is on my local box (i.e.  in the local hard drive, not a mapped drive).

Comment: If the account is running as "local system" then you may have trouble accessing the network, even via svn.  Try running CF as a different user (for example, your own account) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is there any output at all from `cfexecute`?

Comment: I did a cfdump of temp (the variable in cfexecute) and I got "empty string"

Comment: To Jake, please forgive me if this is a stupid question.  But since I am specifying the user name and password in the parameters, wouldn't the specified user name and password be used instead of the ones used by the ColdFusion service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure and trap the output from the cfexecute call. you are not getting a ColdFusion error - but that does not mean you are not getting a command line error (which CF would happily ignore).

Second - I wonder if you have tried removing the 8 character aliases from your script (instead of "progra~1" use "program files(86)"). It takes a little wrangling because you have to put them in quotes (usually).

Finally - as others have suggested it could be a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using "Program Files" instead of Progra~1.  No difference in terms of the result.

Comment: Rats.. thought that might be a smoking gun (sigh).

Comment: I wish I could mark Jake's response as the answer because it was a permission issue.  But since his response is a comment, which I cannot mark as the answer, the next closest one would be Mark's response.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a .bat file and this is what my line looks like
`start "" TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\"`

I know this code work when ran alone as a .bat file. The `start ""` is only useful if you want  to run multiple updates and have them all run concurrently.

I would try running this command and if that fails I would guess it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Have you tried running the bat file in a ColdFusion app?  Or did you run the bat file at command line?  I have Tortoise SVN too.  I have no problem whatsoever running the bat file at command line.  The only problem I have is to run in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking atSVNkit (http://svnkit.com/index.html) since ColdFusion runs on top of Java.  You could either throw it into your CF libs folder or use JavaLoader.  Then you create the Java objects and use them against the SVN directory.

Here's a blog post showing some example code:
http://deploy.alagad.com/blog/post.cfm/svnkit-coldfusion-and-you--very-cool-java-cf-stuff

Also, there's sample Java code for a repository update which should be rewritable with a few CreateObject("java", "...") functions. http://wiki.svnkit.com/Updating_From_A_Repository